# Hyperledger Fabric: How to return error in Java chaincode so it goes back to fabrik-java-sdk client

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

let's say my Java chaincode (running on Fabric 1.4.4) wants to throw an exception to show that the new asset to be created already exists. I am throwing a RunTimeException with the problem or error (In this case, "Contract LL00001 already registered") which is logged in the Peer node executing the transaction:

```
2019-11-29 20:15:37.807 UTC [peer.chaincode.nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.1.4] func2 -> INFO 16a8ec Contract LL00001 already registered
2019-11-29 20:15:37.807 UTC [peer.chaincode.nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.1.4] func2 -> INFO 16a8ed java.lang.RuntimeException: Contract LL00001 already registered
```

But then, after the stack trace I see that the peer node is returning it as 500 error without includeing my error description or any reference to the error Exception in java (this makes sense as that error is language agnostic):

```
2019-11-29 20:15:37.807 UTC [peer.chaincode.nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.1.4] func2 -> INFO 16a8ff 20:15:37:804 SEVERE  org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeInnvocationTask call                   [1f56a053] Invoke failed with error code 500. Sending ERROR
```

Which is logged in my client java application (which uses fabrik-java-sdk):

```
org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.InvalidArgumentException: Proposal response is invalid.
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ProposalResponse.getChaincodeActionResponsePayload(ProposalResponse.java:272)
    at ...
```

So I just know that there was a problem from the chaincode, but I can't know what the problem is. How can I get the error type and description so I can show the problem to the user? Now I need to go to the peer node an check logs there to see what problem is.

Note: I am extending the new org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractInterface in my chaincode class.

Update: peer node logs the error exception (org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeException) and seems to return correctly the error message ("The document was not found") in the 500 response as shown in log, but this message does not get to Java SDK

```
2019-12-23 22:11:09.178 UTC [peer.chaincode.nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.9.7] func2 -> INFO 5aa7 22:11:09:176 SEVERE  org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeInnvocationTask call                   [12cc4ad0] Invoke failed with error code 500. Sending ERROR
2019-12-23 22:11:09.179 UTC [peer.chaincode.nid1-blockchain-hapeer1-mrrc-0.9.7] func2 -> INFO 5aa8 22:11:09:177 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$2 accept                 > sendToPeer 12cc4ad09a1feb7fc1246ac04bf69509204ca74368be2c7e4bbf0a503e90417f
2019-12-23 22:11:09.181 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 5aa9 [mrrc][12cc4ad0] Exit chaincode: name:"mrrc"  (36ms)
2019-12-23 22:11:09.181 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 5aaa [mrrc][12cc4ad0] failed to invoke chaincode name:"mrrc" , error: transaction returned with failure: The document was not found
```

Edit: It seems to be a error in Java SDK. I have created a JIRA issue in Fabric's JIRA:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABJ-508

Answer (score 0):

To throw this error back to your fabric java sdk client, one way would be to make your chaincode class extend the ChaincodeBase class (which can be imported in your java program by importing **org.hyperledger.fabric.shim** ) and then you can use its ***newErrorResponse*** method in each of your chaincode methods to throw your custom errors wherein you can provide the error string as it's first (or only) parameter. You can possibly have a look at this example from the fabric samples repo:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/abstore/java/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric-samples/ABstore.java#L28

To have a look at the overloaded implementations of the ***newErrorResponse*** method, so that you can see what other possible params you can pass to it, please follow:

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java/fabric-chaincode-shim/1.4.0/source-code/org/hyperledger/fabric/shim/ChaincodeBase.java

**UPDATE** : If you are using the newer chaincodeInterface (as suggested by [icordoba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194735/icordoba)) for your chaincode implementations instead, then you should throw an instance of ChaincodeException class which can be imported by importing org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeException, to achieve the same, you can have a look at a sample chaincode [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/blob/master/fabric-chaincode-shim/src/test/java/contract/SampleContract.java#L60)

Comment: Thanks Udyan for your reply. Correct me if I'm wrong but ChaincodeBase is the old way to develop Java chain code. I am using the new org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractInterface in my code. Which uses the annotation @Transaction() to mark chaincode annotations. How can I do this with ContractInterfact and not ChaincodeBase? Thanks.

Comment: @icordoba it could be a bug and if it is you might want to try raising an issue at jira.hyperledger.org. Make sure you select the `fabric-chaincode-java` component.

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour? I mean, what should the exception and message captured in java-sdk-client? I am not sure it's a bug but something I'm missing when executing the method using the sdk.

Comment: Hi @icordoba , actually I work on node chaincodes, so did not know about the same. Please have a look at the latest edit, maybe it might be the one we both have been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @icordoba It should behave the same as node chaincode so there should be a way of getting the exception message back to the client. It sounds like a jira may still be appropriate because if it is working but not obvious then examples and doc are required. They have also just changed the way to raise issues and java chaincode should now have it's own project to select in jira.

Comment: Thanks @UdyanSharma. I have tried using the ChaincodeException but Java client still throws a InvalidArgumentException. Following the code I see that it just checks if response is invalid and throws InvalidArgumentException (ProposalResponse.java line 272) which in my opinion is a weird exception to throw in such situation). I'll add the issue in JIRA.

Comment: Update: I see that peer returns the error in the 500 response. I update the issue with this information